# Bash Script - fswatch trigger bash function

Tags: bash, shell, triggers, filesystems, fswatch

I have a bash script where I want to trigger a method every time the filesystem is changed:

```
#!/bin/bash

function run {
    echo Do some magic
    // Do some magic
}

run

fswatch . src | 'run'
```

In this case I am watching the `src` folder.

When I trigger the script via

```
./automater.sh
```

the script executes the `run` function the first time correctly and when I then change some file, the script simply exits...

Comment: i figured out that when i use *fswatch . src | ./automater.sh run*, it works fine, BUT then it runs in a loop.... why?

Comment: Does your `run` function contain a loop reading the events from standard input? If not, then your code must be changed to `fswatch . src | while read -r changed_path; do run; done`

Answer (score 2):

`BUT then it runs in a loop....`, I also hit this, because after your `./automater.sh` execution, there are some new file changes in your directory, you can use exclude option to ignore these files, in my case like:

`fswatch -l 5 -o -e ".*" -i "\\.py$" . | while read; \
    do \
        unittest || true
    done`

- -l, check file changes every 5 seconds
- -o, to batch all changes to one number
- -e, exclude file, ".*" means exclude all files firstly
- -i, include file, "\.py$" means include all .py files
- `|| true`, seems need to make your command return true when your use in shell script, I use this trick to solve `only first time correctly` issue

Also you can run `fswatch . src` and your 'run' command in separate terminal window to find what are the newly changes are.